# Terminology for a graph obtained from another by adding edges

Tags: graphs, terminology

$H$ is a supergraph of $G$ if it can be obtained from $G$ by adding, edges, vertices, or both.

Is there a standard terminology for a graph that can be obtained from $G$ only by adding edges?

Comment: Sometimes it's called a *closure* (e.g. the transitive closure is a special case of a supergraph $H$ obtained only adding edges). However the term is only applied when you are adding all edges in order to obtain a property of the graph, so I don't think it is used as a generic term.

Answer (score 3):

If $H$ is made by adding only edges to $G$, then $G$ is a *spanning subgraph* of $H$. However, I'm not aware of any way of phrasing it that makes $H$ the subject of the sentence.

Comment: "spanned supergraph" ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 3):

In *graph modification algorithms*, a graph $H$ is called a *completion* of $G$ if there exists a set of edges $F \subseteq [V(G)]^2$ such that $G+F \cong H$.

You can search on arxiv for examples such as

- ([Proper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3472)) [Interval Completion](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3473)
- [Chordal Completion](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2230) (more often called Minium Fill-In for historical reasons)
- [Cograph Completion](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4011)
- [Chain Completion, Threshold Completion, Trivially Perfect Completion](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4022) (warning: own contributions)
- General [$H$-free Completion](http://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02688)

See also:

- [Complexity Status of Edge Modification Problems](http://fpt.wikidot.com/complexity-status-of-edge-modification-problems)
- A paper called [*An Overview of Kernelization Algorithms for Graph Modification Problems*](https://scholar.google.no/scholar?q=An+overview+of+kernelization+algorithms+for+graph+modification+problems) by Liu, Wang, and Guo.

Answer (score 2):

We often think of a graph as the set of its edges, the vertex set being fixed. This is not a universal point of view, but is common enough. In that case you can just write $H \supseteq G$, and say that $H$ is a supergraph of $G$. Just make sure that you explain what you mean by these notations.

Generally speaking, *subgraph* is ambiguous — it's not clear whether you're allowed to remove vertices. *Supergraph* is somewhat less common, and suffers from similar ambiguity. Whenever a notion is ambiguous, and you are worried that the reader won't be able to guess correctly from context, you should explain clearly what you mean, humpty-dumpty style.